# FileNotFound exception when executing jar file

Tags: c#

I'm creating a epubchecker gui using c#

there is a free epubchecker written in java.

its call epubcheck

to run using command line

```
java -jar epubcheck.jar file.epub
```

and my c# code is

```
System.Diagnostics.Process clientProcess = new Process();
clientProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
clientProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @" -jar " + @"C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\epubcheck-4.0.1\epubcheck.jar" + " " + @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\v3.epub";
clientProcess.Start();
clientProcess.WaitForExit();
```

and the error is

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

but i checked the location of the jar file and epub

i copied the string on my program and pasted the string on file explorer. and the file and folder exist.

so what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Add path to `java` to environment `path` variable.

Comment: still doesn't work. the error are still the same. i use this 

;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin

the java file is inside the bin folder

Comment: @knowme, logoff and relogin in Windows or reboot it. Anyway, chech path variable befor starting. In can differ for x32 and x64.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have spaces in your file path, you need to surround them in quotes:

```
clientProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @" -jar " + @"""C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\epubcheck-4.0.1\epubcheck.jar""" + " " + @"""C:\Users\User\Desktop\v3.epub""";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   clientProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @" -jar " + @"C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\epubcheck-4.0.1\\epubcheck.jar" + " " + @"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\v3.epub";
```